# Angular Form can not update Validation by a dynamic angular form

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

I have now a problem with a angular form, which can not update dynamically validation in a dynamic angular form.

In this example, there is a select, which can choose either a email or phone, and under this selector, there is a input field, which can be either a email or a phone number.

But the problem is, the validation child component will be not updated, if the value of select changed.

the code is as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of contactForm.get('information').controls; let informationIndex = index">
              <div [formGroupName]="informationIndex">
                <div fxLayout="row" class="parameterWrapper">
                  <div class="parameterLabel step">type</div>
                  <label>
                    <select class="parameterInputSelect" formControlName="type" (change)="setContactValidation($event, informationIndex, contactFormIndex)">
                      <option *ngFor="let param of getContactInformationTypes(false)" [value]="param">{{param}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div fxLayout="row" class="parameterWrapper">
                  <div class="parameterLabel step">detail</div>
                  <label>
                    <input class="parameterInput" type="text" formControlName="detail" [value]="item.controls.detail">
                  </label>
                  <app-validation-errors type="detail" [control]="item.controls.detail" [selectedValue]="selectedInfoType"></app-validation-errors>
                </div>
              </div>
```

in this code, you can see a select and a input field. And also a child component validate-error.

in the ts file

```
public setContactValidation(value: any, infoIndex: number, contactFormIndex: number): void {
    this.selectedInfoType = value.target.value;
    const information = this.contactFormData.controls[contactFormIndex].get('information') as FormArray;
    let validator = [];
    switch (this.selectedInfoType) {
      case ContactInformation.TypeEnum.EMAIL:
        validator = [Validators.email];
        information.controls[infoIndex].get('detail').setValidators(validator);
        break;
      case ContactInformation.TypeEnum.PHONE:
        validator = [Validators.pattern(VALIDATORS.ONLY_NUMBER)];
        information.controls[infoIndex].get('detail').setValidators(validator);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    information.controls[infoIndex].updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

but, if I select email, the validation in input field is not working. How can I update child component validation-errors, if slect value changed.

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the validator, but not removing the old one.

Whenever you change to Email you need to remove the existing validator before setting Email validator. I hope you get my point.

Comment: setValidator replace one validator by other, the problem is that when you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call updateValueAndValidity() for the new validation to take effect

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that When you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call updateValueAndValidity() for the new validation to take effect.

Any way, I suggested create a custom form validation. As depending from two values, remember when change the type use form.get('detail').updateValue

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <select formControlName="type" 
          (change)="form.get('detail').updateValueAndValidity()">
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="phone">phone</option>
    </select>
  <input  formControlName="detail">
  <div *ngIf="form.get('detail').errors">
     {{form.get('detail').errors|json}}
    </div>
  </form>

form=new FormGroup({
    'type':new FormControl('email'),
    detail:new FormControl(null,this.validatorType())

  })

  validatorType()
  {
    return (control:FormControl)=>{
      const form=control.parent?(control.parent as FormGroup):null
      if (form)
      {
        if (form.get('type').value=='email')
          return Validators.email(control)
        else
          return Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]\d*$/)(control)
      }
     
      return null
    }
  }
```

you can see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dwjjjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)